# CKFinder - 404 Error when attempting an upload

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I set my CKFinder/CKEditor integration as follows:

```
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor11');
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, null, { type: 'Files', currentFolder: '/archive/' });
```

The CKFinder popup displays and I go to the upload tab and am able to select an image. When I click "Send it to the Server" I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its 
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is 
temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that 
it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /ckfinder/connector

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 
Version:4.7.2110.0
```

I get a similar error when I click "Browse Server" on the Image Info tab. I see nothing else in the documentation that is required. Please help me to solve this issue

Edit:

Adding connectorPath fixed it. The path is different on our DEV server than my local machine, where it works already.

```
            CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, {
                connectorPath: '/brainsbeta/ckfinder/connector'
            });
```

Comment: What is your server configuration? It looks like some paths rewriting issue.

Comment: Indeed. See my edit. Thanks.